# Ambiguity in NameError:

Tags: python

The code works fine when I set the attribute lyrics to lyrics_bday it gives a NameError in case of lyric_bulls or lyrics_tamasha. Why is that so?

```
class Song(object):
def __init__(self, lyrics):
    #self.lyrics is the instance while lyrics is the attribute
    self.lyrics =  lyrics_bday

def sing_me_a_song(self):
    for line in self.lyrics:
        print line

lyrics_bday = ["\n Happy Birthday to you", "\n I dont want to get sued", "\n So I'll stop here"]
happy_bday = Song(lyrics_bday) #passing the variable to class

lyrics_bulls = ["\n They rally around the family", "\n With pockets full of shells"]
bulls_on_parade = Song(lyrics_bulls)

lyrics_tamasha = ["\n Pal bhar sambhal jao", "\ndil ko kaise samjhaun", "\nAgar tum sath ho"]
agar_tum_sath_ho = Song(lyrics_tamasha)

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

Comment: Why does `__init__` take a `lyrics` argument if you're not going to use it?

Comment: use `self.lyrics =  lyrics` in `__init__`

Comment: Happy Birthday is in public domain now, you won't get sued any more.

Comment: I understand the right answer is setting self.lyrics to lyrics. I want to understand why does it give the expected output if I set it lyrics_bday but an error in case of lyrics_bulls and lyrics_tamasha?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do in `__init__` but as of now your code only contains assigning value to lyrics; 
In `__init__` you are assigning `lyrics_bday` to `self.lyrics` and you are taking argument as `lyrics` hence you need to use `self.lyrics = lyrics`
but if you are calling function then why not pass argument in it? see below code example:

```
class Song(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # ... include your desire code here
        self.default_lyrics = ["*-"*10,"DEMO","lyrics..........","*-"*10]

    def sing_me_a_song(self, lyrics=None):
        if not lyrics:
            lyrics = self.default_lyrics
        for line in lyrics:
            print(line)

song_object = Song()
lyrics_bday = ["\n Happy Birthday to you", "\n I dont want to get sued", "\n So I'll stop here"]
lyrics_bulls = ["\n They rally around the family", "\n With pockets full of shells"]
lyrics_tamasha = ["\n Pal bhar sambhal jao", "\ndil ko kaise samjhaun", "\nAgar tum sath ho"]

song_object.sing_me_a_song(lyrics_bday)
song_object.sing_me_a_song(lyrics_bulls)
song_object.sing_me_a_song()
```

Output:

```
 Happy Birthday to you

 I dont want to get sued

 So I'll stop here

 They rally around the family

 With pockets full of shells
*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
DEMO
lyrics..........
*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
```

as you can see you don't need to create class object every time; just pass the argument when it's necessary, and considering `__init__` you can use predefined value of lyrics to be printed if no lyrics passed to function.